# Regex Remove Unmarked

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am having problems with some Regex; I need to find everything in between quotes and everything not in between to be deleted. Now marking the quotes is easy enough just simply

```
".*?"
```

with dot matches new line (matches newline). So now I have everything marked that I need, can I simply just delete everything NOT found by this search? Why is it so difficult to do this--delete unmarked text; the concept itself is extremely simple.

I am using Regex on notepad++.

Next, I'll need to remove the first 2 quotes, unquote *x* quotes after this and format in the way shown below. But I am struggling with even the basic concepts so far; I need someone to put me back on track.

```
"foo" "bar" "..." "..." "..." "baz"    -->    ..., ..., ..., baz
```

and

```
"foo" "bar" "" "...                    -->    ......, baz
..." "baz"
```

Comment: why does "foo" and "bar" get deleted? aren't they in quotes?

Comment: Re: point 1, can't think of a way round this. REGEX acts on what it matches, not what is not matched. This would be trivial if REGEX allowed negation of sequences (rather than just single characters at a time), but alas...

Comment: They "foo" and "bar" are in quotes but they are unneeded data.

Comment: @Utkanos: So why is Regex like that- what is stopping the implementation of this?

Comment: Good question. You would have thought that, if it can check positively for a sequence of chars, it can also check negatively for one. I'm sure there's some deep, internal reason. Ironically it *can* negate sequences in the sense of negative look behind/ahead assertions - just not in the middle of the pattern :)

Answer (score 0):

Delete everything up to the first quote:

```
Search: \A[^"]+
Replace: (nothing)
```

Match anything in quotes and any following non-quote characters, replacing with the quoted text:

```
Search: ("[^"]*")[^"]+
Replace: $1
```

I'm assuming that `\A` matches the start of the text and that `$1` refers to a capture group in Notepad++'s flavour of regex.